# Overwriting the login admin page sonatauser

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change the page admin login in sonatauser which is in sonataproject/userbundle/admin/Resources/views/admin/security/login.html.twig
But I can't find a solution because the file extends the base template.
Can someone give a solution for such problem?

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="connection">
        <form action="{{ path("sonata_user_admin_security_check") }}" method="post">

            {% if error %}
                <div class="alert alert-error">{{ error|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}</div>
            {% endif %}

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="big sonata-medium"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="big sonata-medium" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="remember_me">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
                    {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend the SonataUserBundle to override the login template.

Follow the [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html#extending-the-bundle) on how to install an extended bundle of SonataUserBundle.
If you don't have the sonata:easy-extends:generate command available, you should install [SonataEasyExtendsBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html).

You create login.html.twig in Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Security and add the [default code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/2.2/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig) (assuming you are using the SonataUserBundle 2.2). Then you can customize it.